# Support vector machines for mutliple object categorization

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, svm

I am trying to use linear SVMs for multi-class object category recognition. So far what I have understood is that there are mainly two approaches used- one-vs-all(OVA)  and one-vs-one(OVO).
But I am having difficulty understanding its implementation. I mean the steps that I think is used are:

- First the feature descriptors are prepared from let's say SIFT. So I have a 128XN feature vector.
- Next to prepare a SVM classifier model for a particluar object category(say car), I take 50 images of car as the positive training set and total 50 images of rest categories taking randomly from each category (Is this part correct?). I prepare such models for all such categories (say 5 of them).
- Next when I have an input image, do I need to input the image into all the 5 models and then check their values (+1/-1) for each of these models? I am having difficulty understanding this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one-vs-all approach, you have to check for all 5 models. Then you can take the decision with the most confidence value. `LIBSVM` gives probability estimates.

In one-vs-one approach, you can take the majority. For example, you test 1 vs. 2, 1 vs. 3, 1 vs. 4 and 1 vs. 5. You classify it as 1 in 3 cases. You do the same for other 4 classes. Suppose for other four classes the values are `[0, 1, 1, 2]`. Therefore, class 1 was obtained most number of times, making that class as the final class. In this case, you could also do total of probability estimates. Take the maximum. That would work unless in one pair the classification goes extremely wrong. For example, in 1 vs. 4, it classifies 4 (true class is 1) with a confidence 0.7. Then just because of this one decision, your total of probability estimates may shoot up and give wrong results. This issue can be examined experimentally.

LIBSVM uses one vs. one. You can check the reasoning [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f419). You can read [this](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/RifkinK03.pdf) paper too where they defend one vs. all classification approach and conclude that it is *not* necessarily worse than one vs. one.

Answer (score 2):

In short,  your positive training samples are always the same. In one vs one you train n classifiers with negative samples from each of the negative classes taken separately. In one vs all you lump all negative samples together and train a single classifier.. The problem with the former approach is that you have to consider all n outcomes to decide on the class. The problem with the latter approach is that lumping al negativel object classes create may create a non homogeneous class that is hard to process and analyse.