# One vs one multiclass classification using LibSVM

Tags: matlab, libsvm, face-recognition

I am doing one vs one multiclass classification for face recognition using LibSVM MATLAB. I have a doubt on the labeling of data. The class 1 will be features of face 1 , class 2 will be features of face 2 and so on. What will the negative class of the models be?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22211971/1586200) answer of mine. May be useful to you.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: I went through the link, thank you. Just want to clarify if i got it right: Considering i am using one-vs-one classification for face recognition and i have images of 3 people in the database. So model 1 will be positive class(+1) face 1 images and negative class(-1) face 2 images, model 2 will be positive class(+2) face 1 images and negative class(-2) face 3 images, model 3 will be positive class(+3) face 2 images and negative class(-3) face 3 images ?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. The above procedure will be followed for training in one-vs.-one multiclass classification