# Is my implementation of confusion matrix correct? Or is something else at fault here?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm, feature-extraction

I have trained a multi class svm classifier with 5 classes, i.e. `svm(1)...svm(5).`

I then used 5 images not used to during the training of these classifiers for testing.

These 5 images are then tested with their respective classifier. i.e. If 5 images were taken from class one they are tested against the same class.

```
  predict = svmclassify(svm(i_t),test_features);
```

The predict produces a 5 by 1 vector showing the result.

```
-1
 1
 1
 1
-1
```

I sum these and then insert it into a diagonal matrix.

Ideally it should be a diagonal matrix with 5 written diagonally when all images are correctly classified. But the result is very poor. I mean in some cases I am getting negative result. I just want to verify if this poor result is because my confusion matrix is not accurate or if I should use some other feature extractor.

Here is the code I wrote

```
  svm_table = [];
  for i_t = 1:numel(svm)
      test_folder = [Path_training folders(i_t).name '\']; %select writer

         feature_count = 1; %Initialize count for feature vector accumulation

      for j_t = 6:10 %these 5 images that were not used for training
          [img,map] = imread([test_folder imlist(j_t).name]); 

          test_img = imresize(img, [100 100]);
          test_img = imcomplement(test_img);

          %Features extracted here for each image.
          %The feature vector for each image is a 1 x 16 vector.

          test_features(feature_count,:) = Features_extracted;
          %The feature vectors are accumulated in a single matrix. Each row is an image

          feature_count = feature_count + 1; % increment the count
      end
      test_features(isnan(test_features)) = 0; %locate Nan and replace with 0
      %I was getting NaN in some images, which was causing problems with svm, so just replaced with 0

      predict = svmclassify(svm(i_t),test_features); %produce column vector of preicts
      svm_table(end+1,end+1) = sum(predict); %sum them and add to matrix diagonally
  end
```

this is what I am getting. Looks like a confusion matrix but is very poor result.

```
-1     0     0     0     0
 0    -1     0     0     0
 0     0     3     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     1
```

So I just want to know what is at fault here. My implementation of confusion matrix. My way of testing the svm or my selection of features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to add some issues:

1. You mention that: << These 5 images are then tested with their respective classifier. i.e. If 5 images were taken from class one they are tested against the same class. >>

You are never supposed to know the class (category) of test images. Of course, you need to know the test category labels for calculating various metrics such as accuracy, precision, confusion matrix etc. Apart from that, when you are using SVM to determine which class the example belongs to, you have to try all the SVMs.

There are two popular ways of training and testing multi-class SVMs, namely one-vs-all and one-vs-one approach. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211971/1586200) answer and its corresponding question to understand them in detail.

I don't know if MATLAB SVM is capable of doing multiclass classification, but if you use LIBSVM then its uses one-vs-one approach. It will also do the testing for you correctly. However, if you want to design your own one-vs-one classifier, this is how you should proceed:

Say you have 5 classes, then train all possible combinations of pairs = 5c2 = 10 pairs ({1,2}, ..., {1,5},{2,1},...,{2,5},...,{5,4}). While testing, you have to apply all the 10 models and count all the votes to decide the final result. For example, we train models for 4 pairs (say), ({1 vs 2}, {1 vs 3}, {2 vs 1}, {2 vs 3}) and the outputs of 4 models are {1,1,0,1} respectively. That means, your 4 predicted classes are {1,1,1,2}. Therefore, the final class is 1.

Once you get all the predicted labels, then you can actually use the command `confusionmat` to get the confusion matrix. If you want to make your own, then make a `5x5` matrix of zeros. Add a 1 to the position (actual label, predicted label) i.e. if the actual class was 2 and you predicted it as 3, then add 1 at the position `(2nd row, 3rd col)` in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues that I can see...

1) What you're using is not really a multi class SVM. Your taking several different SVM models and applying them to the same test data (not really the same thing). You need to look at the documentation for svmtrain. When you use it you give it two kinds of data, the training data (parameter vectors for each training image) and the Group data (vector of classes for the images associated with the vectors..). What you get will be one SVM model which will decide between 1 of the options. (I usually use libsvm, so Im not that familiar with Matlabs SVM implementation, but that should be the gist of it)

2) Your confusion matrix is derived incorrectly (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). Start by making a 5x5 zeros matrix to hold the confusion matrix. Loop through each of your test images and let the SVM model classify the image (it should pick 1 of the five possibilities). Add 1 at the proper position of the confusion matrix. So if the image should classify as a 3 and the SVM classifies it as a 4 you should add 1 to the 3,4 position...